# Stack Overflow knows where I really am!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, privacy

I got really interested in the new Jobs beta being integrated into Stack Overflow. I was particularly intrigued when I noticed a link to my profile:

[image: Create CV link]

Naturally, I followed it. Also, because my existing CV is in French. And not English.

***One thing really scared me:*** It auto-filled my Full Name, and my Location.

Don't get me wrong, CVs are supposed to be professional and presentable, and to do that, you have to have your name and location. I'm not trying to say that I disagree with the fact that fields are auto-filled, but **I'm trying to figure out how SO gets the data.**

While my name is likely retrieved by looking at the internal details of my profile, the location is not. Here's where I am according to my profile:

[image: Toronto, Ontario]

The auto-filled location field did not show that. Instead, it showed my real location, namely another area within Southern Ontario. This is probably obtained using my IP address.

---

### I want to ask one thing:

*Don't get my location from my IP*. If a suitable location that can be validated is available from the profile page, please use that instead. Don't get me wrong, this really scared me initially, and it doesn't feel right that this has to happen, especially when I've already shared such a location with you already.

Comment: I assume that if it's not validated it's ok to auto complete based off IP? as you can see from my profile there is no way it can be validated (unless the KSA have opened a rift and dumped Lucaria on earth)

Comment: It's hard to use the location from the profile. A lot of users don't fill it out or put something random that isn't even a real location like [this jokester over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=profile). It's probably just easier to use the IP address geolocation and let you change it if you want to change it.

Comment: @Memor-X Perhaps, but maybe it should just say, "tell us your location" or something along those lines. I also forgot to mention this, but this entire thing seems somewhat contrary to the Privacy Policy

Comment: @animuson That is a good point. This is probably me overreacting a little bit, but it did kind of catch me off guard. But it feels like we're making seemingly private information, potentially public. But oh well...

Comment: @Zizouz212 your location via IP is never *private* since it's used for geoblocking on some online stores or even on youtube to prevent certain videos being viewed (ie Funimation's) and this is before you even login/register. ofcause if this is just on the form then you can probably assume your location is safe unless you save the form, SE gets hacked or the government order's SE to hand over the data citing some terrorism clause

Comment: @Zizouz212 The privacy policy *specifically* says, "Information we get from your use of the network is [...] your approximate location" so no, it's not in any way a violation of the privacy policy.

Comment: I'm confused. What's "it"? Your SO profile gets your full name? Or your Jobs CV does? Or what?

Comment: @Zizouz212: it is ... a violation, to misuse IP addresses, prob not where you live, but in EU.

Comment: Ahh it's cute, it means they like you, a lot!